# WPF ICommand CanExecute update from other thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following `ICommand` assignment in `MainViewModel`:

```
MineCommand = new ActionCommand(
    c => MineRulesForPolygon(SelectedPolygon, "stringParameter"),
    c => SelectedPolygon != null && !SelectedPolygon.IsLoading 
        && SelectedPolygon.Records != null
        && MinSupport > 0 && MinSupport <= 1
        && MinConfidence > 0 && MinConfidence <= 1
        && !IsMining);
```

First argument is `Execute` and the second is `CanExecute` method. `SelectedPolygon.IsLoading` is true until the data is loaded (`SelectedPolygon` is another ViewModel, which gets selected from a collection of those models):

```
public void LoadData(string latColumn = "latitude", string lonColumn = "longitude", Action postLoading = null) 
{
    if (_context != null)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            if (_context.SelectWithinPolygon(SqlPolygon, latColumn, lonColumn, out DataTable tab))
            {
                Records = tab;
            }
            IsLoading = false;
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
                new Action(() => { postLoading?.Invoke(); }));
        })
        {
            Name = "Polygon Data Loading Thread"
        }.Start();
    }
}
```

You can see me trying almost [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479303/icommand-canexecute-not-triggering-after-propertychanged) solution (is mixed with second answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923686/mvvmlight-canexecute-not-working-until-window-click)). The way of calling `LoadData` from `MainViewModel` is:

```
SelectedPolygon.LoadData(postLoading: () => MineCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged());
```

having `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` as follows:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

To ensure the condition of `CanExecute` is true, I placed the breakpoint at lambda `() => MineCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` directly in parameters, and evaluated those values from `CanExecute`; as expected, evaluation results true. However the button bound to this command remains disabled:

```
        <Button Grid.Row="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Mine"
                Style="{StaticResource CommandButtonStyle}"
                Command="{Binding MineCommand}" >
        </Button>
```

How can I force it to update its `IsEnabled` property according to `CanExecute` change?

Comment: How are you verifying that the breakpoint at lambda `() => MinCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` evalutes to true?  That is not a conditional lamdba expression.  Have you tried instead to directly put the breakpoint on `c => SelectedPolygon != null && ...`? Perhaps one of those conditionals is returning false.

Comment: I don't try to verify. whether this lambda is true, because this method is `void`. I only evaluate those values, when this lambda is about to execute. By the way, the `c => SelectedPolygon != null && ...` is not getting called.

Comment: I was merely repeating what you said in your original post, that you "placed the breakpoint on lambda `() => MineCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`; as expected, evaluation results true".  How (and what) were you evaluating for the results to be true?  If you are now saying that `c => SelectedPolygon != null && ...` is not getting called at all, then you've touched on the reason why your button is still disabled.

Comment: 1. Place the breakpoint to lambda 
2. Stop at this point 
3. Select the whole `CanExecute` condition 
4. Press Ctrl+D, Q
Sure, reason is that WPF does not react on `CanExecute` change -> getter is not called, and the way to solve it is literally my question.